# Set Automate app as a device admin on Fire OS

Tags: device-administrator, fire-os

I'm using Fire OS 7.3.2. I'm trying to set the "Automate" app as a Device admin, but when I click "Grant as device admin" it doesn't do anything. So I then tried to use ADB commands but it only just said "Unknown component".

Can someone please help?

Comment: Is the "grant as device admin" a button in system setting? If so, then Amazon has likely removed the "device admin" feature from their non-standard Android.

Comment: I'm not sure how the Android settings on Fire OS looks like, but can you find Device administrator manually, usually inside Security settings?

Comment: @ballzak Well, yes and no. The system settings are recognized apps by the system. The app I'm trying to activate; is through a system popup menu.

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes, but as my reply to ballzak says, is through a popup menu.

Comment: @borger The system show no such dialog, so it's likely the dialog Automate shown. Try enabling Automate as a device admin in system Security settings instead.

Comment: @ballzak Yes, the system has a built-in popup dialog when an application requests admin permissions. And the system security settings doesn't show "Automate" on the list. P.S: Sorry for the late reply, family stuff.

Comment: @borger Please use in-app Help & feedback menu to submit an issue report.